# Need to analyze C# code to find unreferenced classes

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have legacy C# code and I am using Visual Studio 2008. I am looking for a tool, sort of code-analyzer that would say to me which class are not used and also some other useful information that might useful for code optimization.

If there is exact duplicate please specify.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper) (r#) has something of the sort.

Comment: Indeed but you do get what you pay for :-)

Comment: Where is it in ReSharper? I have a project and I need to gather statistic of not referenced classes. That is somewhere is a class that is not referenced anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Only if the classes are not public.

Comment: I have not seen it in FxCop, which category is it?

Comment: Which, knowing nothing else about the analyzed assembly, is correct behavior (ie, some other assembly could be referencing the classes in another solution).  It'd be cool if there was a switch to toggle this, but the current behavior is correct for the purpose of FxCop.

Comment: Right, only unused non-public methods are detected which is correct as gmagana stated. Uncalled private code produces CA1811: Avoid uncalled private code; category is Microsoft.Performance.

Comment: CA1812 also flags unused internal classes

Answer (score 1):

The [C# Test Coverage](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/CSharpTestCoverage) tool will tell you which code blocks (methods) are not executed during any single (or set) of runs.   If you exercise your code thoroughly, blocks not executed are strong candidates for dead code.